# Create array of same type as passed to method

Tags: java, generics

I have in java a sorter class that takes an array of comparable objects and sorts them. I need to create a temp array for the sort (this is merge sort) and the array needs to be the same type as the type passed in (I think?) I'm getting all sorts of warnings from eclipse no matter what I do.

My method declaration is

```
public <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void sort(E[] data);
```

I read about generics a bit but I'm still confused. Any links to a complete generics tutorial would also be a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: Not a tutorial, but a very in-depth FAQ about generics is [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Could you give an example of the code that gives the warnings?

Comment: I think Java Tutorials on [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) will be the best place to go for learning Generics..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use generics here, and no need to create the temp array of the same type as the type of the argument.

```
public void sort(Comparable[] data) {
  Comparable[] temp=new Comparable[data.size()];
  ...
}
```

Comment: You'll want to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the method, as we can be sure the method is type safe, but the compiler can't.

Comment: $Dunes yes, but even better use <?> type variable: Comparable<?>.

Comment: Correction: data.length instead of data size().

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler will complain about the creation of a generic array though.

Comment: $Dunes I've checked and it does not. Wildcard <?> is not a type variable.

Comment: I did the following
    `E [] tmpArray = (E[]) new Object[data.length];` and then added the @SupressWarnings. Looks like there is no way else to do this. Thanks

Comment: `void sort(Comparable[] data)` is not a good signature. It does not guarantee that the element type is comparable to itself. That's why we have `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`